# Manually start SharePoint 2010/2013 workflow in SharePoint 2013 farm?

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

Is it just my **SharePoint 2013** environment or does anyone else experience the follow issue?

> A **SharePoint 2010 workflow** attached to a **SharePoint 2013 list**
>   cannot be started manually for individual items in the list unless the
>   user has **at least Contribute permissions to the site** where the
>   list is located.

Note the following:

- the **Workflow.aspx** page of a list item (where the workflows can be manually started and where the lists of running and completed workflows are) cannot be accessed (**Access Denied**) if the user doesn't have **at least Contribute permissions** to the site.
- this happens to all users who do not have **at least Contribute permissions** to the site.
- the list has **unique permissions** and users have at least Contribute permissions to it.
- the **workflow history** of a workflow that ran for an item in the list can be **accessed by any user** with access to the list, regardless of the permissions they have to the site.
- the workflows cannot be started manually by a user with **Full Control** on the list unless he has **at least Contribute access to the site**.
- if the site is on a site collection using the **2010 experience version**, then the problem doesn't exist. As long as the user has **at least Contribute permissions** to the list item, he can access the **Workflow.aspx** page and manually start workflows.
- the message that the user sees when trying to access the **Workflow.aspx** (to manually start workflows) is: "*Sorry, you don't have access to this page.*"

Have you experienced this? If yes, how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the case.  I currently have a design change request open with MS to fix this issue and it does sound like that it is going to be fixed in a future CU.

If you reflector the code and take a look, you can see exactly where it is checking for contribute access at the site (SPWeb) scope.

```
// Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.StoreSubscriptionService
public override WorkflowSubscriptionCollection EnumerateSubscriptionsByEventSource(Guid eventSourceId)
{
    this.context.Web.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions.EditListItems);
    WorkflowStore workflowStore = new WorkflowStore(this.context.Web);
    eventSourceId = StoreSubscriptionService.ConvertToGuidToken(eventSourceId, this.context.Web);
    WorkflowFile[] files = workflowStore.QueryWithGuid("0x0100AA27A923036E459D9EF0D18BBD0B9587", StoragePublishState.Unchanged, "WSEventSourceGUID", eventSourceId);
    return this.ConvertToWorkflowSubscriptionCollection(files);
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(HttpContext
>   context)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(Exception
>   ex)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions
>   permissionMask)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.StoreSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByEventSource(Guid
>   eventSourceId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ApplicationPages.WorkflowPage.ConstructStartArray()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ApplicationPages.WorkflowPage.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)

EDIT:
Oops, I forgot to say what we did for the temporary workaround.  Now this workaround sucks, but you basically give everyone contribute access to the site, and then break inheritance to all lists and libraries where the user DOESN'T need contribute access and remove their contribute access.

EDIT 2:
For more details on how I figured this out and the workarounds, I have blogged about it here:  http://steve.thelineberrys.com/unable-to-manually-start-workflows/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It helps to know it is not me, but SharePoint. I thought about the exact same workaround, but it SUCKS so bad. I will be waiting for the CU as  starting workflows manually is not really necessary for my solutions, and where it is, the user has at least Contribute access to the site. Where did you submit your design change request to Microsoft? Is it public to follow it?

Comment: I submitted it through premier support.  No, it's not public.

Comment: In the past when I have submitted bugs to get fixed, there is about a 4 month turnaround until I see the fix in a CU.  So I would expect a CU early next year sometime to contain a fix.

Comment: Oh, btw, the other workaround is to NOT have SharePoint 2013 workflows enabled on the farm. This way it's never checking for any SP 2013 workflows and thus it doesn't do the contribute permission check on the site (spweb).

Comment: I see. Early next year would still be good, I think.
Hmm, I think this workaround doesn't sound bad. My SP2013 farm went live last month and all the workflows I have created are 2010 workflows, so this may not be a bad workaround. I haven't had a look yet at the difference between 2010 and 2013 workflows in VS2013 as that may stop me from unregistering the Workflow service if there are significant improvements in 2013.

Comment: Has there been any update on the ticket that was put in with Microsoft regarding this issue? I have reviewed all of the CUs released for the last 6 months and a fix is not mentioned.

I refuse to believe the only solution to this is to grant the user an elevated permission on the Site object level and HOPE that you broke inheritance on all the children to keep them out of where you don't want them being.

Comment: The latest update I received was this fix is currently in testing and planned for an April 2015 CU release.

Comment: Superb, @SteveLineberry . Thanks for letting us know. I **hope** the fix will be included in the April 2015 CU as they say.

Comment: Ok, we have installed the October 2015 CU and it should now be working as expected.  Please give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: Any news about this ? I got the same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It would seem we're not running September CU afterall. Sorry for the confusion!

*I have tried with the latests September CU update, and I cannot get it to work either.
(Sorry I cannot comment yet)*

Comment: Suggest not to remove as this contributes to the answer.