# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow initiation form: you don't have access to this page?

Tags: workflow, permissions, initiation-form

using a Sharepoint 2013 VisualStudio Workflow with initiation form I wonder why a member of the site can work on the library elements and trigger the workflow but when the workflow tries to show its initiation form only the error page appears with

> sorry, you don't have access to this page

? what might be the problem here ?
the workflow has got its InitiationUrl in the Elements.xml - do I have to set permissions to the initiation form somehow?

or has it got to do with this:
[manually-start-sharepoint-2010-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013-farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115311/manually-start-sharepoint-2010-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013-farm/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a new initiation form we get the workflow to work. So what's the difference? The old form had within its PlaceHolderMain section a WebPartPages:WebPartZone tag. Probably it was copied from another aspx and this led to the sorry error message. So take care what you are doing within an aspx on one hand but on the other hand Microsoft could deliver error Messages which are a little bit more precise...