# "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" when trying to start workflows

Tags: workflow, permissions

My list X has unique permissions. Group A has contribute and approve permission on this list, but only read permissions to the whole site. However, when group A tries to launch a workflow manually in list X (via Files -> Workflows) it says: "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you."

Giving them full control on the list did not solve the problem, but full control on the whole site worked. So I assume that I have to give group A give permissions somewhere else on the site to allow them to launch workflows. But where would it be?

With SP Designer I found the Document Library "Workflows". I gave group A full control to this library, but it didn't solve my problem.

"Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you" appears after clicking this button!
[image: picture of workflow button]

**For future readers**: As stated in an old question (linked in the answer below), the behaviour is by design. A user at least needs to have contribute permissions on the site level, in order to launch workflows manually.

Comment: Is the workflow using any data from other list/library?

Comment: No. But the error occurs even before selecting one specific workflow. It occurs once the user clicks on the general Workflows button.

Comment: What does the workflow do on triggering it?

Comment: The workflows do nothing. They can not get started by the user, because the user can not access them. It's not a problem with a specific workflow.

Comment: have you tried to clear SP designer's cache after changing the permission? You also need to provide the contribute permissions all related lists  like Tasks Lists, History Lists etc. Please validate if you have any hidden list as well.

Comment: @VikasSharma I just stopped inheriting the permissions for Task, Workflow History and Workflows (the document library appearing under 'all files' in SPD) and gave the group contribute rights to these lists. It didn't help. Once again I changed the top-level permissions of the group (to the whole site) from 'read' to 'contribute', which worked out. So I assume there is still some place, I have to grant them permissions to.

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem but unable to that, I am not getting error. However I am also not able to start workflow. I have created a custom permission level (with Edit) and added to the in the list (has unique permission) . And tried to start the workflow. I am not getting error this way. But I can also not see the workflow. I will work on this will get back to you.

Comment: Hey, with above approach, I was able to start the workflow if, I change the settings of workflow "Creating a new item will start this workflow." Hence when I create the new Item, it starts the workflow automatically.

Comment: Hey, really appreciate your help! I also just set up a workflow, which starts on creation. Group A can create items and the automatic workflow works without any problems.
However, if I change this workflow to a manual workflow, they are still not possible to access the workflow overview of one item... (pic in main post).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to share the Root SharePoint Site to `Group A`

- As `Limited Access` to Can view specific lists, document libraries, list items, folders, or documents when given permissions.
- And as `contribute` to the SharePoint list that has the workflow with its related `Task List` and `History list`.

You may also need to check "How to elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013" by doing the following :

- Allow workflow to use app permissions.
- Grant full control permission to a workflow.
- Develop the workflow to wrap actions inside an App Step using SharePoint Designer.

For more details about How to apply the above steps check [The Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

**Update** :

- The behaviour is by design. A user at least needs to have contributed permissions on the root site, in order to launch workflows manually as mention at this thread 
  [Manually start SharePoint 2010/2013 workflow in SharePoint 2013 farm?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115311/manually-start-sharepoint-2010-2013-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013-farm)
- Also, check the latest CU that has been installed , it's preferred to apply Service Pack 1 if it's not applied where maybe this issue solved at it.
  hope it helped you

Comment: But my problem is not that a specific workflow cannot get started or throws an error. My problem is that some users can't access the site, on which they could select which workflow shall run on an item.

Comment: Follow up on your edit: The group already has read permissions (+ limited access) to the root site. Contribute to the Task List and History List did not help (see comment section).

Comment: Ok let's try to investigate this issue , are this issue occurred for all associated list workflow or only this workflow !

Comment: Workflows that are started on creation or on edit work fine. But any workflow that shall be launched manually by the user, cannot be started, because the group can't access the workflow overview of one item.

Comment: is App Management Service Started ,  I prefer if we can continue on chat  ?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43357/discussion-on-question-sorry-this-site-hasnt-been-shared-with-you

Comment: For future readers: As in the old question linked in the answer, the behaviour is by design. A user at least needs to have contribute permissions on the site level, in order to launch workflows manually.